# How to register a SPI implementation when running exec:java

Tags: java, maven, classloader, vert.x, serviceloader

I'm trying to make [VertX Mertrics](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-dropwizard-metrics/java/) work when running via the `exec:java` Maven plugin.

All works as expected when I package the application into a fatjar and run it with `java -jar fat.jar -conf config.json -Dvertx.metrics.options.enabled=true`

When I run it with `mvn clean package exec:java -DskipTests` I see:

`2016-03-22 18:39:58.833 WARN  i.v.c.i.VertxImpl:348 - Metrics has been set to enabled but no VertxMetricsFactory found on classpath`

I tried several approaches:

- adding `io.vertx:vertx-dropwizard-metrics:3.2.1` as compile dependency
- create an in-house metrics implementation and register it by means of `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VertxMetricsFactory` file (double-checked that it's actually copied to `target/classes/META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VertxMetricsFactory`)
- also adding `${basedir}/src/main/resources` as additional classpath element (in addition to previous point)

I have double-checked in the debugger that `ServiceLoader` actually returns an empty iterator.

This is my exec-plugin config:

                `<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalClasspathElements>
                            <element>${basedir}/src/main/resources</element>
                        </additionalClasspathElements>
                        <mainClass>io.vertx.core.Launcher</mainClass>
                        <commandlineArgs>run ${vertx.mainVerticle} -conf ${vertx.config}</commandlineArgs>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <systemProperty>
                                <key>vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name</key>
                                <value>io.vertx.core.logging.SLF4JLogDelegateFactory</value>
                            </systemProperty>
                            <systemProperty>
                                <key>vertx.metrics.options.enabled</key>
                                <value>true</value>
                            </systemProperty>
                        </systemProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>`

Here is `exec:exec` configuration that **does work**, but I want to understand if and why it's (im-)possible to do it with `exec:java`

`<profile>
            <id>exec</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <executable>java</executable>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>-Dvertx.metrics.options.enabled=true</argument>
                                        <argument>-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=${vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name}</argument>
                                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                        <classpath />
                                        <argument>io.vertx.core.Launcher</argument>
                                        <argument>run</argument>
                                        <argument>${vertx.mainVerticle}</argument>
                                        <argument>-conf</argument>
                                        <argument>${vertx.config}</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `exec:exec` instead of `exec:java`?

`exec:exec` runs in a separate process, and this might solve your problem.

`ServiceLoader` uses the application class loader to load any classes listed in `META-INF/services`. This is why `ServiceLoader` often does not work in environments with custom class loaders (e.g. OSGi).

Since Maven constructs its own class loader for each Maven plugin, even if you declare compile time dependencies containing your SPI, these classes will only be visible to the Maven class loader, but not to the application class loader.

Comment: I know I could use `exec:exec` (as this would be equivalent to running java directly from CLI). I'd be interested to find out how exactly Maven classloader precludes using ServiceLoader. Where can I find the details for how the custom classloader is expected to operate? What if I added the SPI to the plugins deps?

Comment: There are no special requirements for a custom class loader. It's the difference between ServiceLoader.loadClass(Class) and ServiceLoader.loadClass(Class, ClassLoader). If the SPI consumer uses the first variant without explicit class loader, then the system class loader will be used.